# WebTestClient with get() and requestBody not available

Tags: java, rest, integration-testing, spring-webclient, webtestclient

I have an application where one of the api is defined with Get method. It also expects request body which then gets mapped to POJO. I am trying to test this controller using webTestClient. But I do not see an option to send request body with get() method. Not sure if I am defining my webTestClient in the right way.

My controller looks like:

```
@GetMapping
public Flux<ResponseBody> getAllResources(@RequestBody Resource resource) {
//related code here...
}
```

My Test method:

```
@Test
public void myTest() {

webClient.get()
.uri("uri_path")
.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
.accept("application/json")
.exchange()
.expectedStatus.is2xxxSuccessful();
}
```

I was thinking since it is allowed in the controller to bind the object to POJO with the get call, there should be some way to test it using webTestClient.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use:

```
webTestClient.method(HttpMethod.GET)
```

instead of:

```
webTestClient.get()
```